# How to filter for IPv4 addresses with the Resolve-DnsName command?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to resolve a known Hostname to the IPv4 address with the Resolve-DnsName command in Powershell. This works fine but it also displays the IPv6 address that is unnecessary in my usecase.

I have already tried to filter by type but I cannot get it to work proberly.

```bsh
Resolve-DnsName "MyServer" | Where-Object {$_.Type -ne "AAAA"}
#Type AAAA is for IPv6 and A is for IPv4
```

I expect that the ouput to show only the IPv4 address but it still displays both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Does resolving public names work any better? Say, `Resolve-DnsName -Name www.google.com | ? { $_.Type -ne "AAAA" }` ? There's typo in your code, so please double-check the command. Copy and paste text instead of typing to avoid such errors.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=win10-ps), the `-Type` parameter specifies the DNS query type that is to be issued. Try `Resolve-DnsName -Name "MyServer" -Type A`. P.S. You mistyped `Resolve` (forgot the `v`)

Comment: Thanks I corrected the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was just temporary problem. Now it works perfectly fine without any changes. I still do not know what caused this strange behaivor.

Still thanks for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Then just select the IP v4 address from the object?

```
Resolve-DNSName 'MyServer' | select IP4Address
```

Comment: (hostname | Resolve-DnsName).IP4Address